# Bitcoind listtransactions return only received transactions not showing send payment

Tags: json-rpc, php, error

I try to get all transaction of an account using this:

listtransactions Ammadkhalid

But this is show me received transaction not send here screenshot but in php:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is because 'accounts' don't really exist, except to help you to keep track of what address receives what.

`listtransactions` without an account name should show you the sends, as I believe all transactions get sent with the default account, or `*`

Comment: But the its show all not the only address who send have that tx so there is any send that i can show how much balance send ? by address

Comment: No, because there is no https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/From_address

Comment: then please can u give any solution to i can only all tx who send and received :( please bro help me its important

Comment: There is no from. You have to trace the transactions yourself if you want to find where the coins were sent to prior. There are no commands to show data that does not exist.

Comment: then how to get ? total balance i just only want to show total balance after sending coins to anyone

Comment: Just do `listtransactions` or `listtransactions ""`. Sent transactions are always debited from account "", unless you you sendfrom, in which case it debits the account you specify.